# High Cache Miss From Memcache When Storing Sessions

Tags: php, session, memcached

We have been having problems with the memcache server storing sessions data, the cache miss was about 20%, therefore we added in another pool of memcache servers, but now the cache miss rate is up to 50%. Any possible cause or solutions for this problem?

Comment: Do you have multiple servers connecting to the memcache pool?

Comment: Cache miss rate is decreasing, but users are still continuing to report errors. Is there any more possible causes?

Answer (score 2):

In your php.ini file, the value for `session.save_path` should not include 127.0.0.1 or localhost.

Use the hostname or LAN ip for the memcached servers.

See the first item in the troubleshooting section [here](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#Troubleshooting_common_problems).

Comment: Nope, we're using LAN IPs, here's an example: tcp://172.23.111.12:11211. We currently have only 2 servers.

Comment: @TheOnly92: are they listed in the same order on both servers? *order matters* for the hash algorithm to work properly.

Comment: Oh yes, the orders are different, I will try to fix it by tomorrow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TheOnly92 did it help or could you fix it somehow?